# Remotely retrieve model number of camera

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, camera

I am currently engaged in a desktop sharing session with a remote computer running windows XP.  There is an external video camera connected to the computer but I do not know which model number it is.  Is there a way I can determine which model camera this is there?  I am trying to retrieve this information so I know which cable I need to buy.

Answer (score 4):

Ok,
What about pictures metadata?
If you have the pictures has made by this camera,
check the picture Properties>Details
Is the camera model there?:)

Comment: Forgot to specify that this is a VIDEO camera.  Looked through a captured movie and the meta information does not appear to have anything about the model number.

Answer (score 2):

Start->settings->control panel->system->Hardware->Device Manager

Device manager SHOULD list the camera and hopefully the model if it is detected.

Comment: Nope.  The device manager lists the camera under "imaging devices" but it only lists "Sony DV Camcorder" and does not list the full model number.

Comment: Is there any sony camcorder software installed?  It may pick up the model number if you open it and check settings.

Comment: Also check the driver listed under device manager to see if it is model-specific.

Comment: Also check driver `Properties -> Resources` and see if any of those properties have an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer, right click on the camera drive letter, select properties, then the hardware tab, the model number should be in the list

Comment: There is no hardware tab.  Just general and color management.  Neither of them list the model number.